# Find texture pixel on 3D mesh

Tags: uv, bmesh, texture-coordinates

I have a complicated mesh of a real object that I created with a 3D camera.  The mesh has a corresponding large texture that maps onto the mesh.  I imported the mesh into Blender and then applied the material.  Other than that, I am operating in Blender Python.  My goal is to find certain features on the texture using computer vision and then map those features to the 3D mesh.  Ultimately, I want have a robot work on the real object based on the locations I map from the image to the mesh.

1. The image is (16384, 16384, 3)--so 268435456 pixels (16384*16384).
2. The mesh has 258533 vertices and 517786 faces.  Each face has 3 loops.
3. The mesh has 1553358 UV coordinates.

I'd like to choose a pixel on the image (say the center pixel--8192, 8192) and then see where on the 3d mesh that pixel is mapped.

I would appreciate any tips on this problem.  So far, I am flummoxed!

Alex